# Is this a valid email address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, rfc

```
"Françoise Lefèvre"@example.com
```

I'm reading [RFC 5321](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt) to try to actually understand what constitutes a valid email address -- and I'm probably making this a lot more difficult than it needs to be -- but this has been bugging me.

> ```
>                i.e., within a quoted string, any
>                ASCII graphic or space is permitted
>                without blackslash-quoting except
>                double-quote and the backslash itself.
> ```

Does this mean that [ASCII extended character sets](http://ascii-table.com/ascii-extended-pc-list.php) are valid within quotes? Or does that imply [standard ASCII table](http://ascii-table.com/ascii.php) only?

**EDIT** - With the answers in mind, here's a simple jQuery [validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) that could work in supplement to the the plugin's built-in email validation to check the characters.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ascii_email", function( value, element ) { 
    // In compliance with RFC 5321, this allows all standard printing ASCII characters in quoted text.
    // Unquoted text must be ASCII-US alphanumeric or one of the following: ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~   
    // @ and . get a free pass, as this is meant to be used together with the email validator

    var result = this.optional(element) || 
        (
            /^[\u002a\u002b\u003d\u003f\u0040\u0020-\u0027\u002d-u002f\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005a\u005e-\u007e]+$/.test(value.replace(/(["])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1/, "")) &&     
            /^[\u0020-\u007e]+$/.test(value.match(/(["])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1/, ""))   
        );
    return result;
}, "Invalid characters");
```

The plugin's built-in validation appears to be pretty good, except for catching invalid characters. Out of the test cases listed [here](http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/code/showvalidemail.php) it only disallows comments, folding whitespace and addresses lacking a TDL (ie: @localhost, @255.255.255.255) -- all of which I  can easily live without.

Comment: In general, the best answer to this sort of question is the address is valid if you can get a couple different MTAs to accept it. The IETF standards don't always specify things as clearly as you might want.

Comment: Don't validate the individual characters. [Rather validate the syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/1931322#1931322).

Comment: @BafusC I *do* validate the syntax. I would also like to stop people from cramming Sanskrit into an ASCII-only field. The two are not mutually exclusive. I do realize however that true email validation with a RegEx, is as one redditer put it, is "like building a house using nothing but a power drill." Client-side validation is only there to tell someone "hey, this doesn't belong" -- and I believe this is a good, simple way of doing that.

Comment: Also, that regex in that link is terrible. I don't know why it was voted up like that. It's alright to accept bad emails, but you can't have a script turn away tons of perfectly valid ones. It fails on something as simple as john+doe@example.com. Please, webmasters, if you don't want to put in the effort to do client-side validation correctly, just don't do it at all. Instead, fire off an email and see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this MSDN page the extended ASCII characters aren't valid, currently, but there is a proposed specification that would change this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(VS.90).aspx

The important part is here:

> Thomas Lee is correct in that a quoted
>   local part is valid in an email
>   address and certain mail addresses may
>   be invalid if not in a quoted string.
>   However, the characters that others of
>   you have mentioned such as the umlaut
>   and the agave are not in the ASCII
>   character set, they are extended
>   ASCII. In RFC 2822 (and subsequent
>   RFC's 5322 and 3696) the dtext
>   specification (allowed in quoted local
>   parts) only allows most ASCII values
>   (RFC 2822, section 3.4.1) which
>   includes values in ranges from 33-90
>   and 94-126. RFC 5335 has been proposed
>   that would allow non-ascii characters
>   in the addr-spec, however it is still
>   labeled as experimental and as such is
>   not supported in MailAddress.

Answer (score 4):

In this RFC, `ASCII` means `US-ASCII` , i.e., no characters with a value greater than 127 are allowed. As a proof, here are some quotes from RFC 5321:

> The mail data may contain any of the 128 ASCII character codes, [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Systems MUST NOT define mailboxes in such a way as to require the use in SMTP of non-ASCII characters (octets with the high order bit set to one) or ASCII "control characters" (decimal value 0-31 and 127). These characters MUST NOT be used in MAIL or RCPT commands or other commands that require mailbox names.

These quotes quite clearly imply that characters with a value greater than 127 are considered `non-ASCII`. Since such characters are explicitly forbidden in MAIL TO or RCPT commands, it is impossible to use them for e-mail addresses.

Thus, `"Francoise Lefevre"@example.com` is a perfectly valid address (according to the RFC), whereas `"Françoise Lefèvre"@example.com` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, but read on:

> While the above definition for
>   Local-part is relatively permissive,
>   for maximum interoperability, a host
>   that expects to receive mail    SHOULD
>   avoid defining mailboxes where the
>   Local-part requires (or    uses) the
>   Quoted-string form or where the
>   Local-part is case-    sensitive.

...

> Systems MUST NOT define mailboxes in
>   such a way as to require the use    in
>   SMTP of non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 spec has an [interesting take on the issue of valid email addresses](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#valid-e-mail-address):

> A valid e-mail address is a string that matches the ABNF production 1*( atext / "." ) "@" ldh-str 1*( "." ldh-str )  where atext is defined in RFC 5322 section 3.2.3, and ldh-str is defined in RFC 1034 section 3.5.

The nice thing about this, of course, is that you can then take a look at the open source browser's [source code for validating it](https://bug555559.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=461895) (look for the `IsValidEmailAddress` function).  Of course it's in C, but not too hard to translate to JS.